# Mpdf how to add dependency in a .module file

Tags: php, drupal, mpdf

**Drupal 7**

*Iam trying to generate Pdf via mpdf so how to perform this event and how to add the dependency* ..

The code which iam using

**require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';** //what should be added

```
$html = '
<h1><a name="top"></a>mPDF</h1>
<h2>Basic HTML Example</h2>
This file demonstrates most of the HTML elements.

<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
';

$mpdf=new Mpdf;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

This is the error iam getting
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add mPDF library on your Drupal site

First, you have downloaded the mPDF package from below URL (http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)
They unzip the folder into /sites/all/libraries path

Note: No need to add code to include the mPDF's autoload file, It will be added by default from the library folder

In addition, you will find the mPDF module for Drupal, Here you will have more option to reduce your time

Module path: https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf

Comment: now iam getting       this   `code`  <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal7/sites/all/modules/poc3/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal7/sites/all/modules/poc3/poc3.module</b> on line <b>124</b><br /> `code`

Comment: Did you download and add the library in /sites/all/libraries/ path? if you have added the library then no need to add require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; in your module file

Comment: i have added like this   require_once __DIR__ . '/libraries/mpdf/mpdf.php';